# Printing an index of a list

Tags: python

Hey beautiful community :)

I have this code:

```
list1 = ['aaaa', 'bbb', 'c', 'ddddd', '', 'ff']

def getLongestStringIndex(list_of_strings):
    longest_string = ""
    for string in list_of_strings:
        if len(string) > len(longest_string):
            longest_string = string
    return longest_string

print(getLongestStringIndex(list1))
```

I had a task to do it without max function so I dont need to change a lot of the code, but instead of printing the longest string, I need to print the longest string INDEX, so it will return 3

What I need to do to make it done ?

EDIT: I've been asked to do it without .index method and enumerate ..

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Simple for loop from 0 to len(list1) - 1.

Comment: Didn't got it, can you expand?

Comment: Method #2 of [Iterate over a list in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/).

Comment: What should the output be if several strings have the maximum length?

Answer (score 3):

I solved that in a short and pythonic way!

```py
>>> strings = ['aaaa', 'bbb', 'c', 'ddddd', '', 'ff']
>>> strings.index(max(strings, key=len))
>>> 3
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're iterating over the string list, keep track of the current position in the list (`enumerate` is a handy way to do that).  When you find a longer string, remember that position.

```
def getLongestStringIndex(list_of_strings):
    longest_length = 0
    longest_position = 0
    for position,string in enumerate(list_of_strings):
        if len(string) > longest_length:
            longest_length = len(string)
            longest_position = position
    return longest_position
```

Comment: Any option without .index and enumerate ? Possible with range?

Comment: Sure, you could keep track of position yourself and increment it each time through the loop, without using `enumerate`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you just need a tiny modification.

```
list1 = ['aaaa', 'bbb', 'c', 'ddddd', '', 'ff']

def getLongestStringIndex(list_of_strings):
    longest_string = ""
    for string in list_of_strings:
        if len(string) > len(longest_string):
            longest_string = string
    return list1.index(longest_string)

print(getLongestStringIndex(list1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but forgot to mention - but I've been also asked to do it without .index method :(

Comment: Whether or not .index is allowed, the solution should not use .index. It's inefficient to effectively iterate over the list twice.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this without the use of `max()`, `list.index()`, or `enumerate()` is by iterating over the entire list and storing the index of the longest string found.

However, we can bypass the *entire* list iteration by directly finding the longest string and only needing to obtain its index. Assuming of course there are no other restrictions on what to do if more than 1 string is the longest string. Here is an example of how this can be accomplished:

```py
list1 = ['aaaa', 'bbb', 'c', 'ddddd', '', 'ff']

def getLongestStringIndex(list_of_strings):
    longest_string = sorted(list_of_strings, key=len, reverse=True)[0]

    idx: int
    for k in range(len(list_of_strings)):
        if list_of_strings[k] == longest_string:
            idx = k
            break
    return idx
```

Note: This is especially helpful if the longest string is closer to the beginning of the list since the iteration will be much faster, but if the longest string is near the end or at the end of the list then this method is potentially slower than the initial solution I proposed.

### Edit (Better Solution)

A much more Pythonic way to do this is with this one-liner which keeps the list indices "mapped" to the sorted list:

```py
def getLongestStringIndex(list_of_strings):
    return sorted(range(len(list_of_strings)), key=lambda k: len(list_of_strings[k]), reverse=True)[0]
```

Comment: Sorting is inefficient: it O(n * log(n)), while this can be done in O(n)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille You are correct, however, this is just one example of a solution that could be used. It's nice because it can be expanded on for more features later like finding the 3 longest strings instead of just 1. Also, I'm not sure how `sorted()` works but generally Python's built-in functions have a C backend which could be more efficient than O(n) in Python.